# Angular drag-drop

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-dragdrop

I need some reference for angular drag and drop, I went through the angular documentation but it's not working, I need to develop a page where I can drag tools to my canvas in angular.
If anyone knows this please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `@angular/cdk` and it is supporting packages .

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-drag)

Then include a module called `DragDropModule` in `app.module`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ,DragDropModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in `app.component.css`

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; } /* to remove the top and left whitespace */

html, body { width:100%; height:100%; } /* just to be sure these are full screen*/

canvas { display:block; background-color: red } /* To remove the scrollbars */
```

lastly in `app.component.html`

```
<canvas #ele id="canvas" ></canvas>
  <div draggable="true" (dragend)="create()">
  Drag 
</div>
```

in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, VERSION,ViewChild,ViewContainerRef,ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { DraggableComponent } from './components/dragg.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
      componentRef: any;
      count=0;
  @ViewChild('ele', { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){

  }
  create(){
    
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DraggableComponent);
        this.componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
        this.count++;
        this.componentRef.instance.text = "Draggble" +this.count;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks ffor the information, but i need the replica to be dragged, its like  when we deisgn a logo we can drag and drop the tools, actually we are moving the replica right?

Comment: you can add `cdkDrag` to any element to make it draggable

Comment: please use this link for further info , https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/exploring-drag-and-drop-with-the-angular-material-cdk-2e0237857290

Comment: I have seen that, but instead of moving the entire <div> I need to only move the replica. i.e, like dragging clip arts in the paint. can you helo me with it.

Comment: can you join in this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216969/angular-drag-and-drop)

Comment: sorry for the delay can you join the room?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference from here [drag-drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-drag-drop). I generally use this tool for drag and drop. Make sure you will get a solution.

After that, if you get any error then write it down over here.

Comment: I did the same firstly but it won't work.  [this](https://stackblitz.com/angular/brlbpydmpvjn?file=src%2Fmain.ts) is the example I have referred to but the thing won't drag around.

Comment: you mean, you need to drag out of the dotted line correct?

Comment: i want it dragged exactly inside the box, but it won't get moved.